# Saving data from HTML form on server?

Tags: php, html, css, forms

How do i save data from a HTML form on a server?

Here is my code:

```
<form action="?action=save" name="myform" method="post">

<textarea class="textBox" name="mytext"> </textarea>
<input type="submit" class="save" value="save"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to change the action name to point to where the PHP code will be. I put my PHP code on the same page as my HTML and changed the action to save.php (that's my file name where the PHP is).

This is my **save.php** file where everything is.

```html
<?php
// Check if form is submitted and we have the fields we want.
if(isset($_POST["mytext"]))
{
 $file = "data.txt";
 $text = $_POST["mytext"];

 // This file will create a data.txt file and put whatever is in the POST field mytext into the text and put a new line on the end.
 // The FILE_APPEND allows you to append text to the file. LOCK_EX prevents anyone else from writing to the file at the same time.
 file_put_contents($file, $text . "\r\n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Save POST Data</title>
</head>
<body>

<form action="save.php" name="myform" method="post">

<textarea class="textBox" name="mytext"></textarea>
<input type="submit" class="save" value="save"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way its set action on save.php and in this file put

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST)){
        file_put_contents('file.txt', json_encode($_POST));
    }
```

Comment: You need an \r\n to create new lines in the .txt too.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the submit event by js, and send the data to server by using Ajax or fetch. Then in your server side, build an API to catch the request and store data in database or any file you want to store your data.

Best